# software for drawing really nice textbook-quality graphs?

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

Wolfram Alpha is great for graphing functions, and I feel bad criticizing it.  However, let's face it, the diagrams and figures in our textbooks are much nicer.  Consider the following figures of $y=-(x-2)^2+4$ over $0<x<4$:

[image][image]

Obviously, the first figure is *much* better.  The second figure (generated by wolframalpha.com) doesn't even indicate that (0,0) and (4,0) are excluded from the graph.  But besides that, the left drawing simply looks much nicer and more professional.  Not surprisingly, it comes from a textbook.

So, my question is, are there any software tools available for making really nice textbook-quality graphs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can export the code for geogebra graphs if you are a noob and cant use pgfplots or tikz

Comment: Just do a little work with _Plot Options_ in Wolfram Mathematica

Comment: I don't think the graph on the left looks nicer at all. It _does_ use explicit symbology to indicate the missing endpoints, but at the expense of obliterating part of the actual curve. There may be pedagogical reasons why the textbook uses the style on the left rather than the right, but "more professional" does not seem (to me) to be one of them. My main complaint about the WA graph is that it uses unequal horizontal and vertical scales where that is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

PSTricks in LaTeX can create nice graphics. Here is an example and the PSTricks which created it.

[image: PSTricks Graph]

```
 \begin{figure}
 \centering
  \scalebox{1.5}{
  \begin{pspicture*}(-0.75,-1.5)(3.5,1.5)
 \psaxes{<->}(0,0)(-0.75,-1.5)(3.5,1.5)
 \psplot[linecolor=red,plotpoints=500]{0.01}{3.5}{x x 1 x sub mul exp}
  \end{pspicture*}
  }
 \caption{Graph of $y=x^{x(1-x)}$}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: That looks cool, I will check it out, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB is fairly robust and tweak-able but I'm honestly not a fan. Python's `pyPlot` has a MATLAB-like interface and is very extensible. Asymptote is a vector graphics language designed for PostScript and $\LaTeX$ and is capable of drawing complex figures. PGFPlots is a similar package designed specifically for plotting, based on PGF/TikZ. You can also take a deeper look at Mathematica's plotting options, they allow for virtually infinite customization depending on your proficiency in Mathematica.